# how to use jquery alert plugin with asp.net button control?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a bootstrap modal for register users.I want to show a jquery alert to user after successful register or for some alerts.Here is my Button.

```
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <asp:Button ID="btnn_register" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary"  Text="register" OnClick="btnn_register_Click" ValidationGroup="aaa"  />
  </div>
```

the code behind:

```
            protected void btnn_register_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
//some code
        if (bluser.check_username() == true)
        {
            this.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "asdf", "info()", true);

        }

        else
        {
                 //do something
            if (Page.IsValid)
            {

//some codes

            }
```

and my script:

```
            <script>
        notie.setOptions({
            colorSuccess: '#57BF57',
            colorWarning: '#D6A14D',
            colorError: '#E1715B',
            colorInfo: '#4D82D6',
            colorNeutral: '#A0A0A0',
            colorText: '#FFFFFF',
            animationDelay: 300,
            backgroundClickDismiss: true
        })

        function info() {
            notie.alert(4, 'some information', 2)
        }

        }
    }
    </script>
```

But when I run the code it does not work.
Anyone can help me?

Comment: Please help me...thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Did you set a breakpoint and see if the page is actually getting to the line of code that registers the script? If not then the problem is in your `bluser.check_username()` function.

Also, your `<script>` tag needs to look like `<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">` if it doesn't already.

Comment: Yes, I set  breakpoint and my code worked correctly. Also I set type=text/javascript for script tag but it does not fix.